# WPF Combobox, bind a collection<items> where item has a bool property isSelected?

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, selecteditem

I have a List< Versions> where Version, amongst others has the properties VersionUUID, Label, SKU and IsSelected. I would like to bind this to a Combobox and have the selected item just select the IsSelected flag (unselected any previous set flag).

Note:The combobox is in a template, used inside a datagrid cell, so I can not just bind a SelectedItem to the model!

What I have so far is working, the datagrid updates the DB as expected, however the initial value is not set onLoad. If one version already has a IsSelected=true, I would like to have that showing int the Combobox, but it is always empty unless i Select one from the list.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="dtDatagridVersionSelector">
        <ComboBox Margin="0" Width="90"  Style="{StaticResource DatagridComboBox}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Versions, Mode=OneTime}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
                    <RadioButton Focusable="false"  IsEnabled="true" 
                                  GroupName="{Binding VersionUUID}" 
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0"  Text="{Binding Label}"/>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Margin="3,0,0,0" 
                                       Text="{Binding SKU}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </RadioButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" 
                        Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Also, the use of the Radiobox is not written in stone, if there is a better solution to achieve this so only one item isSelected, I'm all open for it

Thanx for any pointers
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SelectedItemConverter x:Key="selectedItemConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" SelectedItem="{Binding Students, Converter={StaticResource selectedItemConverter}}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
</Grid>
```

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
        Students.Add(new Student() { Name = "HArish", RollNo = 1, IsSelected = false });
        Students.Add(new Student() { Name = "Arev", RollNo = 2, IsSelected = false });
        Students.Add(new Student() { Name = "Pankaj", RollNo = 3, IsSelected = true });
        Students.Add(new Student() { Name = "Deepak", RollNo = 4, IsSelected = false });
        DataContext = this;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RollNo { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class SelectedItemConverter : IValueConverter
{

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is IEnumerable<Student>)
            return ((IEnumerable<Student>)value).Where(s => s.IsSelected).FirstOrDefault();
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanx for your detailed example @ethicallogics. I implemented this converter many times last night in any way I could think of, and it never ended up selecting the initial item. Coded up your example this morning, implemented my radio/single selection and it worked as expected. Thanx